# MongoDB Follow/Unfollow Schema Design

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a follow/unfollow feature, where I need to design mongodb schema.

Users can follow, users, posts, pages etc. They can obviously unfollow as well.

I came up with following schema:

```
{
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  contentType: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  contentId: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }    
}
```

My question is how can I track the unfollow case, shall I add a `deleted: Date` and always create a new entry for `follow` action. or shall I create `updateHistory: Array` to keep track of all follow/unfollow actions. What schema is better to go with.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve your question?

Comment: I just answered my own question, you have have a look basically I used `deleted: Date` and created new record for follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it is using `SoftDelete`. I always create a new record for follow and if some unfollow again then I added `deleted: Date`. This way I kept track follow/unfollow history.

Comment: It will be very nice if you could include nosql schema for `Users can follow, users, posts, pages etc.`